# ¿Como puedo llenar una matriz que una sola haya un numero?

Tags: java

tengo una duda  como puedo realizar lo siguiente:

se van a registrar los votos de 5 personas para elecciones de alcalde de la ciudad de Mérida en cual participial 4 candidatos. cada persona puede votar por un solo candidato el cual registra con un uno y por los candidatos que no voto con un cero.

mi duda es como para que en cada fila solo haya un 1 y  el resto de las posiciones de la fila haya un 0, alguna sugerencia  ?

```
 public void votar() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                votos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de su candidato: "));   
                     /* 
                    - si presiono un 1 vota por el candidato 1(y el resto de candidatos dé la fila 1 
                      debería ser  0) 

                    - si presiono 2 vota por el candidato 2(el resto de candidatos  0) de la fila 2 y 
                     así  sucesivamente  */  


               //LOGIICA....

            }

        }
    }
```

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void votar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            votos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de su candidato: "));   
        }
    }
}
```

Analicemos tu codigo..

Recorremos de 0 a 3 algo.. (que no especificas que es.. supongo sera una matriz)
Recorremos de 0 a 3 otro algo (sera una matriz?)

por cada fila y columna =>
obtenemos un numero del usuario...

y no hay mas codigo...

La primer pregunta es... porque recorremos la matriz?

Imaginando tu logica, si cada fila es un votante, y cada columna es a quien votamos, no necesitamos recorrer las columnas.. solo las filas...

o sea.. tu codigo seria

```
public void votar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        votos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de su candidato: "));   
    }
}
```

Ahora... para designar un 1 en algun lugar.. y 0 en el resto, suponiendo que el numero que ingreso es la persona por la cual se voto, entonces pongamos un 1 en esa posicion.. y 0 en el resto... y ahora si, recorramos por columna ;)

```
public void votar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        votos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de su candidato: "));   
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (votos = j) //chequealo, no es exactamente asi
            {
                //aca va un 1 en la posicion de la matriz
            }
            else
            {
                //aca va un cero, porque por este no voto...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacerlo asi

```
public void votar() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            num_candidato = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de su candidato: "));
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if(num_candidato = j){
                    //poner uno en la posicion[i][j]
                }else{
                    //poner cero en la posicion[i][j]
                }
            }

        }
    }
```